# Build apk with different resources in Android

Tags: android, build, colors, resources

Let me explain.

The fact is that I have a app and we need to customice it, the drawables are SVG based xml so changing the colors would be enough to change all the style of the app. So the idea would be build the apk with a different color resource that is ubicated in src.main.res.values.colors.xml in a way that when we reference it from the main code:

```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>     <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>         android:shape="rectangle">
>         <solid android:color="?android:colorBackground" />
>         <stroke
>             android:width="1dp"
>             android:color="@color/transparent" />
>         <corners android:radius="@dimen/avatar_corner_radius" />
>     </shape>
```

As we see the transparent resoure in this case, we use the transparent color from the src.main.res.values.colors.xml but im looking to use a different resource ...colors.xml.

Could be possible?

Comment: Use product flavors, one per customized edition of the app, where you swap in the appropriate colors resource values.

Comment: But in the product flavours I must duplicate the code ?

Comment: @PedroPizarroHuertas No. Specify only those colors in the separate flavor which you want to overwrite. The rest can remain in the `main` folder. Gradle will do a resource merge. All resources which are specified in a specific flavor will overwrite resources in `main`.

Comment: @Alexander Hoffmann Thanks you very much I'll check it =)